# Containerized Odoo with Nginx reverse proxy not creating https webhook in Stripe

Tags: nginx, proxy, odoo, stripe-payments, webhooks

I have a containerized Odoo docker image running over https with an nginx container as a reverse proxy.  Everything works fine overall, but when I try to generate the Stripe payment webhook it is creating it with http instead of https protocol.  While this technically is working, it should be secured.

After some testing, it seems Odoo takes seems Odoo is getting the http protocol from the proxy_pass line in the nginx configuration, where I'm using http to pass traffic to the Odoo container. Any idea how I can make the proxy https to Odoo so it will create the webhook properly, but continue to use http for the proxy_pass since https isn't really needed as these containers are on the same server?

My nginx configuration file is below to show what I have currently. Everything failed to create the webhook from Odoo to Stripe with https.  Appreciate any help, hints or feedback.

```
## Set appropriate X-Forwarded-Ssl header

map $scheme $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl {

  default off;

  https on;

}

upstream test-stream {

   server odoo:8069;

}

server {

    listen      80;

    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # ACME-challenge used by Certbot for Let's Encrypt

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {

      root /var/www/certbot;

    }

    location / {

        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;

    }

}

server {

    listen 443 ssl http2;

    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name example.com;

# removed cert, logs, and etc. related lines for brevity

    # Tried this line before the location block to pass https, not working

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl;

    location / {

          proxy_pass http://test-stream;

          proxy_set_header Host $host;

 

   #####################

    # Tried the following lines to pass https, but none worked

    ####################      

          proxy_set_header Scheme https;

          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Scheme https;

          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

   }

}
```